# jQuery.ParseJSON returns a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm getting a string which represents a JSON Object (it's a valid JSON string according to JSONLint).

When I call :

```
console.log(JSON.parse(datasource_graphe_un));
```

It returns a string, confirmed by :

```
console.log(typeof jQuery.parseJSON(datasource_graphe_un));
```

returning string.

Here's an example of the string I try to parse :

```
[ {"id":195197,"val":9800,"date":"2009/05/11","ax":1242023901,"number":8,"valval":9200} , ... ]
```

Why can't I parse it ? And why jQuery.parseJSON returns a string ?

Thank's

Comment: If that example is the actual return value, you have an array, not JSON. What is `JSON.parse` actually returning?

Comment: It returns an array containing an object for me. http://cl.ly/Pvkj

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](http://jsbin.com/otobat/2/edit). Can you build a fiddle ?

Comment: Yes, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/FGLEu/) for me too.

Comment: Are you sure your didn't stringify it twice ?

Comment: Okay so I tried on my code and it appears that when I try JSON.parse(_I_WRITE_MY_STRING_HERE_) it works, but when I try JSON.parse(_The_variable_containing_the_string_) it does not.

Comment: @Nontenda: How are you creating that variable?

Comment: I'm getting it with a .NET webservice, when I console.log it it shows the correct string.

Comment: @Nontenda: Are you sure `typeof datasource_graphe_un` is a string.  Did you do `var datasource_graphe_un = <% $var %>;` or `var datasource_graphe_un = "<% $var %>";`?  Because in the first one, your JSON is *already* an object, since JSON syntax is JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Yep it's a string, I call a webservice with AJAX `success: function (e) { var datasource_graphe_un = e.d; }` and it's a string (according to typeof).

Comment: What is the first character of `datasource_graphe_un` ? `[` or `"` ? `console.log(datasource_graphe_un[0])`

Comment: Alright it works... I don't know why but when I try : `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(datasource_graphe_un);` it returns the correct object (and yes it is twice). Don't know why.

Comment: @Nontenda - At this point, it's fairly obvious that data was encoded twice.

Comment: I ran into this same problem.  encoded twice :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chrome's Console, this line works fine for me. You may have to iterate through your array if you are trying to parse several results being stored in the variable datasource_graphe_un.

```
  var k = $.parseJSON('{"id":195197,"val":9800,"date":"2009/05/11","ax":1242023901,"number":8,"valval":9200}');
```

Comment: This should have been a comment. But this has already been said in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, probably twice encoding (e.g. you use JSON.stringify() and then encodeURIcomponent()).